# Method to load image data for TPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tpu

So currently both keras.ImageDataGenerator and tf.data.Dataset are not working with tensorflow TPU, Is there any Other method to load image data for training model on Tpu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GCS buckets.

Or you read from files:

```
with open(image_path, "rb") as local_file:
  img = local_file.read()
```

And then convert to tensor and create dataset with tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices.

Comment: reading from tensor_slices would more or less efficient than GCS buckets?

Comment: I didn't compare, but I think that the both aproaches should be similar